# Точка строго внутри четырехугольника

Tags: c++

Дан вектор длины 4 точек выпуклого четырехугольника в произвольном порядке, а также произвольная точка P. Необходимо определить, лежит ли эта точка строго внутри четырехугольника. Все найденные мной алгоритмы предполагают, что точки расположены в каком-то порядке и/или могут находится на границе.

```
struct Point {
   int x, y;
};

bool is_strictly_inside(const Point& P, const std::vector<Point>& points) {
  //
}
```

Comment: Надо - определяйте!

Comment: @goldstar_labs как?

Comment: Упорядочиваем вершины, чтоб получить выпуклый четырехугольник ABCD. Рассматриваем принадлежность треугольнику ABC и ACD (принадлежность треугольнику вообще предельно проста). Ну и все... Только вот что такое "вектор длины 4 точек"? Надеюсь, что координат?

Comment: @Harry а как их упорядочить?

Comment: @Harry 'вектор длины 4' ... точек выпуклого четырехугольника

Comment: Ну, вариантов-то всего 3 - ABCD, ABDC, ACBD. Если он *заведомо* выпуклый - просто смотрите, какой из них выпуклый - в том порядке точки и располагаем.

Comment: @Harry тогда нужно ещё функцию проверки на выпуклость писать

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, это кажется верным решением

Comment: @user261418 нет, неверное. С такой проверкой вы не "поймаете" точку на пересечении диагоналей.

Comment: @PavelMayorov если окажется, что точка лежит одновременно на границах всех 4 треугольников, то это и будет пересечение

Comment: @user261418 сложно получается. Проще тогда уж упорядочить точки, это всего 3 сравнения.

Comment: @PavelMayorov какие 3 сравнения?

Comment: @user261418 векторные произведения: `(x3-x1)*(y2-y1) - (x2-x1)*(y3-y1) < 0`. Сортировка трех точек требует 3х сравнений.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну не знаю, поставить счётчик кол-ва попаданий на границу имхо проще, чем линейной алгеброй заниматься

Comment: @user261418 вам все равно придется ей заниматься, только уже для треугольников :-) Вспомните как проверка принадлежности точки треугольнику выглядит - там та же самая формула.

Answer (score 2):

Вот, нашел :)
Лет 25 назад пробегала мимо меня уже древняя к тому времени книжечка типа "*Математические алгоритмы на Алгол-68*" или что-то типа того, точнее не помню... Некоторые из них я себе на C переписал. Сейчас - "раскопай своих подвалов и шкафов перетряси" (с) - я таки нашел эту реализацию, вдруг пригодится.

```
int PointInPoly(double x, double y, int n, double* x_poly, double* y_poly)
{
    int b=1,i;
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        if ((y<=y_poly[i]) == (y>y_poly[i+1])) {
            if ((x-x_poly[i]) < 
                (y-y_poly[i])*(x_poly[i+1]-x_poly[i])/(y_poly[i+1]-y_poly[i])) b=!b;
        };
    };
    if ((y<=y_poly[n-1]) == (y>y_poly[0])) {
        if ((x-x_poly[n-1]) <
            (y-y_poly[n-1])*(x_poly[0]-x_poly[n-1])/(y_poly[0]-y_poly[n-1])) b=!b;
    };
    return !b;
};
```

Поиск, входит ли (x,y) в `n`-угольник, задаваемый массивами x и y координат вершин.

Вам остается упорядочить вершины :)

Answer (score 2):

Упорядочивание вершин v, чтобы получить выпуклый четырехугольник:

вычисляем 3 z-компоненты векторных произведений i=0..2 [ **v[3]-v[i]**, **v[(i+1)%3]-v[i]** ]
две из них одного знака, одна другого;

выберем индекс той, что отличается, допустим j;

тогда правильный порядок вершин таков: 3,(j+1)%3,(j+2)%3,j.
Составляем новый вектор вершин s.
Проверяем 4 z-компоненты векторных произведений i=0..3 [ **s[i]-P**, **s[(i+1)%4]-s[i]** ], если они все одного знака или 0, то точка находится внутри или на одной из линий, иначе точка вне четырехугольника